# Can't display PyQt4 QSplashScreen window in ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt4

I have some problem to display splash screen in PyQt4 GUI program. The splash window doesn't show when I run the program. And console doesn't show any error. Here is some code:

`class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):`

```
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
      QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, None)
      ...
      ...
      QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pbView,
          QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda: self.view_plot(parent))

  def view_plot(self, parent=None):
      self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap("splash.gif")
      self.splash = QtGui.QSplashScreen(parent, self.pic, 
                      QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
      self.splash.show()
      ...
      self.splash.showMessage(u"Work completed in... {0} %".format(i),
        QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.black)
      ...
      self.splash.finish(parent)
```

Please help!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I understand what wrong - programme couldn't find picture. Cause I write big project and store code file in number of directories

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake, I understand what wrong - programme couldn't find picture. Cause I write big project and store code file in number of directories. Picture file must be in main directory, where we start main window, not in directory where run child-window. Sometimes we need just a time-out and a cup of coffee...